# magento static block error in admin

Tags: php, magento, static, block

I have added the 2 static block codes to a CMS page in magento inside a DIV.

```
<div class="WTcontainerTop">
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="TW_intro"}}
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="TW-Tour"}}
</div>
```

After saving the page, it looks like the below although the frontend page looks fine.

```
<div class="WTcontainerTop">http://everydaycashmere.com/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3tibG9jayB0eXBlPSJjbXMvYmxvY2siIGJsb2NrX2lkPSJUV19pbnRybyJ9fQ,,/key/ba3c67e3bc929ae08551768624139371/ {{block type="cms/block" block_id="TW-wardrobe-Grand-Tour"}}</div>
```

I have tried to fix in a number of times and I don't get this error on other pages. Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that the method of adding static block you tried is correct or not.You can do it by:

Clicking on "Insert Widget" on "Content" portion of 'CMS Page'.

Then select the Widget type to "CMS static Block".Then select the static block you want to add.

This process will add a static block in your cms page.

Hope this will help.

Comment: hi

thank you. This has worked. I have been copying the {{block type="cms/block" block_id="TW_intro"}} into the source panel. I didn't realise there was a widget insertion tool.